How to add a word after every EVEN line and after every selected text using regular expression in Notepad++
I have a m3u file in the following format:
    #EXTM3U url-tvg=""
    #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Sansad.TV.in" tvg-name="Loksabha TV" tvg-  
    logo="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/9/97/
    Sansad_TV.jpg" group-title="News-Hindi",Loksabha TV
    https://hls.media.nic.in/live/lstv/index.m3u8
    #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Sansad.TV.-.Rajya.Sabha.in" tvg- 
    name="Rajyasabha TV" tvg-logo="https://
    static.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/9/97/Sansad_TV.jpg" 
    group-title="News-Hindi",Rajyasabha TV
    https://hls.media.nic.in/live/rstv/index.m3u8
    ...so on

I want to add word "(FHD)" so that input becomes:
    #EXTM3U url-tvg=""
    #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Sansad.TV.in" tvg-name="Loksabha TV (FHD)" 
    tvg-logo="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/
    images/9/97/Sansad_TV.jpg" group-title="News-Hindi",Loksabha TV 
    (FHD)
    https://hls.media.nic.in/live/lstv/index.m3u8
    #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Sansad.TV.-.Rajya.Sabha.in" tvg- 
    name="Rajyasabha TV (FHD)" tvg-logo="https://
    static.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/9/97/Sansad_TV.jpg" 
    group-title="News-Hindi",Rajyasabha TV (FHD)
    https://hls.media.nic.in/live/rstv/index.m3u8
    ...so on

What I have tried:
    Regular expression: (?s-i)(?<=tvg-name=").+?(?=") allows me to     
    select to find the text in whole file.

But I cannot find the expression to replace it and also regular expression to add "(FHD)" after every alternate even line as depicted in the desired output.
Please NOTE:
#EXTINF:......... is a single line in notepad++

Your regex to find is correct:

Find what: (?<=tvg-name=").+?(?=")

then :

Replace with: $0 \(FHD\)

will add  (FHD) after the selected data.

In order to add also  (FHD) at the end of lines that begin with #EXTINF:, you could do:

Ctrl+H
Find what: ^(#EXTINF:.+?tvg-name=".+?)(".+)$
Replace with: $1 \(FHD\)$2 \(FHD\)
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
^               # beginning of line
    (               # group 1
        #EXTINF:        # literally
        .+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
        tvg-name="      # literally
        .+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    )               # end group 1
    (               # group 2
        "               # a quote
        .+              # 1 or more any character
    )               # end group 2
$               # end of line


Nice....what about adding (FHD) to the end of even lines .Please NOTE: #EXTINF:......... is a single line in notepad++ and (FHD) is also present at the end of it.

@ls_milkyway: Please, edit your question and make lines exactly as they should be. I don't understand  which lines are “even”. Do you want to add (FHD) at the end of all lines that begin with #EXTINF:?

@ls_milkyway: Is tvg_name= ALWAYS present in a #EXTINF: line?

answer to both the comments is yes.
